# Grouping images without gaps into a large image

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing a C++ program to place some smaller images on a larger image such that there are no gaps in between the images.
Example:
Given images of sizes 2x2(code 0), 4x4(code 1), 5x5(code 2)
Place them on a larger image of size 4x6
One possible solution could be:

```
0a 0a 1a 1a 1a 1a
0a 0a 1a 1a 1a 1a
0b 0b 1a 1a 1a 1a
0b 0b 1a 1a 1a 1a
```

Another could be of all 2x2 images or a 4x4 image placed elsewhere and 2x2 to cover the remaining gaps.

The best I could think was of is:
1. Select the image of smallest dimension and fill the image with it. 
Maintain its start position in a linked list.(Example: Start for 0a is (0,0).

2.Then select the next larger image (here 4x4) , Make a 4x4 list, Try to replace some set of 2x2 images which are adjacent. Remove those from the 2x2 list and make an entry in the 4x4 list of this image's start point.
3. Keep doing so until no gaps left.

Randomness can be implemented by selecting a random image from the smaller list to make a bigger image.

We are allowed to use any number of copies of images(0a,0b denote 2 copies of image 0) but want to use most of the smaller images to fit to a larger image. 
Are there pre-existing algorithms to solve this problem of placement which are simple to implement and solve the problem guarantying no gaps and also complete randomness?

Comment: What is the magnitude of this problem? I can imagine you can backtrack up to 10x15 sized images.

Comment: Actually I want to avoid backtracking and am looking for a smarter solution maybe by Dynamic Programming or by a greedy approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force approach is simple to implement.  Just start from some arbitrary corner (say the top left), then try putting each of the available shapes at that location: if it fits, find the next not-yet-covered position and iterate through the available shapes there etc..  This can easily be done recursively.

To illustrate how this approach handles your example case of 2x2(code 0), 4x4(code 1), 5x5(code 2) into 4x6, you can concieve of the recursion as exploring a teriary tree with left branches placing a 2x2 code 0 box at the next empty location (X), the middle branch placing a 4x4 code 1, and the right branch a 5x5 code 2.

```
                                            start
                       /                      |                   \
               0a 0a X _ _ _               1a 1a 1a 1a X _         finito
               0a 0a _ _ _ _               1a 1a 1a 1a _ _
               _  _  _ _ _ _               1a 1a 1a 1a _ _
               _  _  _ _ _ _               1a 1a 1a 1a _ _
              /       |                        /         | \
0a 0a 0b 0b X _   0a 0a 1a 1a 1a 1a   1a 1a 1a 1a 0a 0a  finito
0a 0a 0b 0b _ _   0a 0a 1a 1a 1a 1a   1a 1a 1a 1a 0a 0a
_  _  _  _  _ _   X  _  1a 1a 1a 1a   1a 1a 1a 1a X  _
_  _  _  _  _ _   _  _  1a 1a 1a 1a   1a 1a 1a 1a _  _
   /      |  \           /      | \           /     | \
  /       finito        /      finito        /     finito
 /                     /                    /
0a 0a 0b 0b 0c 0c  0a 0a 1a 1a 1a 1a   1a 1a 1a 1a 0a 0a
0a 0a 0b 0b 0c 0c  0a 0a 1a 1a 1a 1a   1a 1a 1a 1a 0a 0a
X  _  _  _  _  _   0b 0b 1a 1a 1a 1a   1a 1a 1a 1a 0b 0b
_  _  _  _  _  _   0b 0b 1a 1a 1a 1a   1a 1a 1a 1a 0b 0b
    /
  etc
```

If you want to speed this up, you could:

- Prune the "codes" being passed down during recursion, so that regions clearly too big to fit in the remaining space aren't considers.  Filtering on both width and height would be ideal, but even filtering on length of diagonal could be useful.
- Save permutations of regions that collectively form rectangular regions, so that you can think of say arrangements covering 10x10, then if solving for 30x20 you don't have to reproduce from scratch  solutions that involve permutations of the 10x10 solutions.  Extending this, you could report solutions as trees.
- Avoid/minimise regenerating from scratch solutions that are mirror images of existing solutions, e.g. by having the outermost loop over "codes" stop after half way.

Comment: But the problem here is that we may need to backtrack a lot if we cannot find a smaller image to fit the gaps or if we find T- or L-shaped gaps.

Comment: You don't need to back-track as such... you just return and let the recursive search try different paths.  Because the approach mentions above finds the "next not-yet-covered position" (say working from left to right, then top to bottom), it doesn't care if there are L shaped gaps... it will attempt to fill them as it goes: if any solutions exist they'll be found.  With that order of traversal, you can never have a "T" shaped gap because that implies shapes packed underneath an unfilled gap.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is checking **if** you **can** fit the smalles images on the big one. In order to do that, you should check the total area of the smaller images and see if its lesser or equal the big image area. If the problem is solvable, you should sort your images by size (descending, biggest first), and use brute force. Keep in mind the sorting part - it'll decrease the number of withdrawals you'll need to do.

Comment: I also want complete randomness.  This algorithm will not lead to all possible achievable solutions.